# How can I integrate Bluemix Conversation and Speech-To-Text and Text-To-Speech

Tags: ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, speech-to-text, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I would like to use the Bluemix Conversation [sample application](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple)
and add speech input and output to it. There are other sample applications for Bluemix TTS and STT available.
What are options to integrate these 3 functions and which of them are recommended for beginners?

Comment: Bluemix and node? If there is not a hard committment to Bluemix, i'd suggest at least looking at the WebRTC samples which cover lots of speech features in a general fashion that may be simple and without the layer of IBM enterprise pixie stuff ( extra complexity may be distraction for learning how things work ). re: https://github.com/andrenatal/speechrtc  https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/  for examples. https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/174118/speech-testing-recognition-in-terminal-on-cli-usin.html

Comment: Hi Robert, thx, will look into this.

Comment: @PeterSchleinitz thx for accepting my answer. I added my own sample project where you can see how I integrated TTS to the conversation-simple app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no immediate plans to provide a 'simple' sample app which demonstrates combining Watson STT (Speech to Text), Conversation, and TTS (Text to Speech). Longer term it is definitely on the radar.

In the immediate term, to get an idea as to how to do this, please take a look at the car-dashboard app code:

- https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/car-dashboard/blob/master/ui/index.html#L85
- https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/car-dashboard/tree/master/ui/ibm
- https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/car-dashboard/tree/master/speech
- https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/car-dashboard/blob/master/ui/ibm/stream_speech_to_text.js#L34

The car dashboard app uses the IBM Watson Speech JS SDK:
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I did something along these lines with the Dialog service demo app and the Speech JS SDK a few months ago:

http://speech-dialog.mybluemix.net/

Full code is on [github](https://github.com/nfriedly/speech-dialog) but almost all of the changes were in [this commit](https://github.com/nfriedly/speech-dialog/commit/fd8408aae59c72797c7974f66a159834e6101bc4).

Note that it was built on an older beta of the SDK. You can get the latest release from [github releases](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/releases) or [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-speech) (for use with webpack/browserify/etc.) and there are lots of [examples](https://watson-speech.mybluemix.net/).

Comment: The Dialog service is now deprecated. Is your code example still relevant?

Comment: Somewhat. The new Conversation service is basically a replacement for Dialog, and it has a more advanced demo with speech built-in: https://conversation-demo.mybluemix.net/ (using a newer version of the same SDK)

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but IBM Watson is still evolving so this may be a more up-to-date answer.

You have 2 options.

You can simply have your app submit an HTTP REST request (either GET or POST) by following this [tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/text-to-speech/tutorial.shtml)

Or you can leverage a language-specific SDK.

If you're using nodejs, then check out this [example](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech-nodejs?cm_mc_uid=17162858992614768165948&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1480203756).

For java, see this [example](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech-java?cm_mc_uid=17162858992614768165948&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1480203756).

**Edit**

Here's an example git project I created to integrate text-to-speech to the conversation-simple sample app: [conversation-simple-with-text-to-speech](https://github.com/kanesee/conversation-simple-with-text-to-speech)

Here's the specific commit where the integration was added: [commit 3564aeb](https://github.com/kanesee/conversation-simple-with-text-to-speech/commit/3564aeb9523bcbbeb64c10f937a2d971a7248f80)